# Converting Stream to ByteString

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I have `Stream` that I need to return through a protobuf message as `bytes`. How do I convert the `Stream` into the `ByteString` that is expected by protobuf? Is it as simple as it appears in the documentation [Serialization](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial#parsing-and-serialization)?

Due to the nature of the project I'm unable to test it well so I'm kinda working blind.
Here is what I'm working with:

Protocol buffer:

```
message ProtoResponse {
   bytes ResponseValue = 1;
}
```

C#

```
public ProtoResponse SendResponse(Stream stream)
{
   var response = ProtoResponse
      {
         // this obviously does not work but 
         // but it conveys the idea of what I am going for
         ResponseValue = stream
      }
   return response;
}
```

I have attempted to convert the `Stream` to a `string` or a `byte[]` but C# compiler in VS keeps showing this error message:

> `Cannot implicitly convert type '' to 'Google.Protobuf.ByteString'`.

I know I am missing something and my knowledge of `Streams` and `protocol buffers` is lacking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, I may have answered my own question. `ByteString` has an extension that accepts a `byte[]`.

```
public ProtoResponse SendResponse(Stream stream)
{
   byte[] b;
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
      b = memoryStream.ToArray();
   }
   var response = ProtoResponse
      {
         ResponseValue = ByteString.CopyFrom(b)
      }
   return response;
}
```

If anyone sees something wrong with this feel free to let me know! Thanks!

Comment: GRPC for me generated method accepting IAsyncStreamReader<MyType> not Stream. Did you converted that?

Answer (score 3):

Im using C#, and Protobuf `syntax = 3;` with `GRPC`. In my case it looks like this:

I found method to change Image to ByteArray, this sample is here to understanding next part of my response.

```
private static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Bitmap image)
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
     image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
     return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

But, next i have to change **Bytearray** to **ByteString** of **Protobuf3**

```
byte[] img = ImageToByteArray(); //its method you can see above
ByteString bytestring;
 using (var str = new MemoryStream(img))
 {
    bytestring = ByteString.FromStream(str);
 }
```

You can simply use `ByteString.FromStream(MemoryStream)` without `CopyFrom` method.

If we take a look to receiver of this message, he need change **ByteString** to **ByteArray** to for example save photo:

```
byte[] img = request.Image.ToByteArray(); //this is received message
```

And thats all. You have exactly the same bytes in both sides.